# Prevent tabbar from changing tab at specific index - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Thanks for reading my question.

I'm trying to implement a popup menu when a user clicks the tab with the index of 4. So I'm trying to prevent the tabbar from switching viewcontroller when index 4 is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:4]){        
        NSLog(@"NO");
        return NO;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"YES");
        return YES;
    }

}
```

I've implemented the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and `self.delegate = self;` in the `viewDidLoad` and it works but just one time.

When I click the index 4 tab the menu shows and the tabbar doesn't switch view (*GREAT*), but when I click it again the view changes even if I get the Log "NO". 
What could be the problem here?

Thanks you for any suggestions!

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Kasaname's answer below I solved it by adding selectedindex and set it to a flag index (prevtab). I change the prevtab to the index of the last selected tab, exept for when the user selects index 4.
My final code:

```
- (BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:4]){
        self.selectedIndex = prevTab; //only change in this method       
        return NO;
    }else{        
        return YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't u use just empty ViewController for the 4th tab?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear methods of your view controller. As per documentation,  this method is called regardsless of whether the selected view controller changed.

Comment: @ProFFeSSoR: What do you mean by `empty ViewController for the 4th tab?`

Comment: @PaperThick: Why are you using `viewController` in `if` condition instead of using the `selectedIndex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {

    } else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {

    } else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2) {

    }
}
```

why dont u use this delegate
Use this delegate it will work i suppose

Comment: how can the `selectedIndex` be 0 if tapped again?

Comment: here selectedindex refers to the index of the tab bar items so it will be alwys one for the first one.

Comment: and in the above vase i have just give the example and its upto to the person how to use and for which selected index

Comment: Thank you that should work just find I post my final code above

Answer (score 17):

This is how you can stop/prevent Tabbar items to switch your tab on tabbar item click

**For Swift 3.0**

Make sure you have implemented **UITabBarControllerDelegate** and set **UITabbarController**'s ***delegate*** to ***self***

then override this delegate in your controller

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[2] {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: it works if you Make sure you are implementing **UITabBarControllerDelegate** and setting **UITabbarController's** delegate = self .

Comment: it's not working even after setting delegate = self
any help?

Comment: @MuhammadUmairGillani you've to set it as self.delegate = self