# How to disable/enable a particular UITabBar Item,

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have 3 tabs in my `UITabbarController`, that I created in my Appdelegate.

When I open the app, I have made the selected tabbarItem the third tabbarItem.

The user can only select the `UITabBarItem` at Index 0, when he is logged in.

I tried every thing to restrict the user from going to `TabBarItem_0` when he is at `TabBarItem_2`.
But nothing worked. I used

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

}
```

But it's not working as I desired. I checked the stackoverflow and found almost the same question, where I found this delegate. But this is not working for me as desired. I googled, but couldn't find any solution other than stackoverflows links, which didn't help this time.

On the click of that disabled TabBar Item, I have to show a pop up. How can I implement that, too?

Comment: What code did you put in that method, what you've got there doesn't actually do anything and will actually probably not compile.

Answer (score 15):

Try something like this,

```
 - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController; 
{    
       if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
            if(isUserLoggedIn)
                return YES;
            else
                return NO;
        }

        return YES; 
}
```

If this does not work then,

Add this after you create the bar bar in app delegate,

```
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:FALSE];
```

once you log in enable it again

```
[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:TRUE];
```

Comment: no not working as desired. Let me explain, for example I am at tabitem_3 and I have to block tabitem_1 then This delegate doesnt stopt it for the First time, more over When I click this tabitem_1 again, the deelgate is not called

Comment: Have a look at this as well,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786556/prevent-tabbar-from-changing-tab-at-specific-index-ios?rq=1

Comment: works but not perfectly, i.e. when I click the Unlock tabs, it works fine, but when I click the the Locked tab, inspite of staying there it goes to the Previous Clicked Tab

Comment: Note that `UITabBarControllerDelegate` needed

Answer (score 9):

Quick hack that i used to present a popup on top of the current view when tapped on a tab bar item.

In your TabBarViewController class, implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and remember to set `self.delegate = self`.

After that

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController.title == "Unique_title" //set an unique title for the view controller in storyboard or the view controller class.
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("YourModalViewIdentifier", sender: nil)
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

That should help you display a modal view when tap is received on the uitabbaritem. I know using title as an unique identifier is bad practice, but just a quick solution to achieve what you want.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in your code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [self checkLogin];
    ...
}

- (void)checkLogin {
    if (!loggedIn) {
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:NO];
    } else {
        [[[[self.tabBarController tabBar]items]objectAtIndex:0]setEnabled:YES];
    }
}

- (void)tapLogin {
  // Do the login action
}

- (void)processLoginResult {
  // Process the result of the login action
  // If the result is success, set 'loggedIn = YES'
  // Otherwise, set 'loggedIn = NO'
  ...
  [self checkLogin];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, it disables the Tab bar, But on the Click of that disabled TabBar Item, I have to show a pop up. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it with the Storyboard, simply selected the TabBarItem in the destination view controller scene and uncheck the Enabled box.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did in Swift 2.1:

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![0].enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you disable a tabbar item in **Swift 3 and 4**

```
tabBarController.tabBar.items![0].isEnabled = false
```