# Overlay button on NativeScript TabView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, angular, nativescript

I have a simple TabView like this using NativeScript w/angular:

```
<TabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" height="300px" (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelectedIndexChanged($event)">
     <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 1'}">
         <Label text="Content in Tab 1"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
     <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Button 1'}">
         <!-- these won't be content here because clicking this should not change to a another tab, but instead should do something else. -->
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab 2'}">
        <Label text="Content in Tab 2"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

I want a button in the tab bar that doesn't change the view, but instead does something else (such as open a modal dialog).

I tried a new `<StackLayout>` both inside and outside of `<TabView>`.

I also tried using an `<AbsoluteLayout>.` All methods caused the app to crash.

Is it possible to capture the tab view change using `selectedIndexChanged` and prevent the change?

I tried `stopPropagation()` on the event but got error:
`Property 'stopPropagation' does not exist on type 'SelectedIndexChangedEventData'.`

I tried changing the view back to the view that existed when the middle button was clicked, but there is a noticeable flicker because the view has to change before this event is even fired. What would have been acceptable is something like `onSelectedIndexWill Change` but that method does not exist.

```
 onSelectedIndexChanged(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {
        if (args.newIndex === 1) { //the middle button
            setTimeout(() => {
                tabView.selectedIndex = args.oldIndex; //go back to the previous view (causes flicker)
                //do stuff for the button click.
            });
        }
    }
```

Or is there another way to incorporate a button in the tab bar that doesn't link to a new view?

Or should I not implement a native tab bar and instead just create a navigation bar from scratch?

**[Here's how it can be done for ios.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786556/prevent-tabbar-from-changing-tab-at-specific-index-ios)**

**[Here is a sample app in NativeScript playground showing the issue. Click center link to see the flicker.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mgaL63&v=7)**

Comment: so basically you want a extra tabbutton in tabbar. but don't want to activate that tab only click? am i right?

Comment: Right. I am looking into the native apis and think capturing `UITabBarController`  `shouldSelect` could be a way to do this. Think of Instagram where the center button in the tab bar (+) just opens a modal.

Comment: try to change tab index to other index without animating when specified tab is selected and do the work you want to do on the tab click. i will give similliar effect you required.

Comment: playground demo has no binding for `onSelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: @bhavinjalodara I don't see how this is possible, particularly with the Angular version of TabView. You can't specify individual index and I don't see any docs on animating tab changes.Am I missing something?

Comment: please provide working playground demo in which flicker can be seen. link you had provides doesn't work as you hadd mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do to the fact that the NativeScript team has refused to [export the delegates](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/2827) this is not something you can monkey patch in at this point.  The only way to do this is to fork the [TabView](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/tab-view/tab-view.ios.ts) code and create your own plugin using it.

However, making this change should be fairly simple once you have your forked copy.  You just need to on around line 64 `public tabBarControllerShouldSelectViewController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, viewController: UIViewController): boolean {`

 You just need to detect which viewController it is trying to load; and then return false in the case where you don't want to actually change the view.  ;-)

Two possible ways;

- check the `owner.selectedIndex`; I believe it should be pointing to the proper new index at this point;
- however if it is not then the second possible method would be to check the `viewController` against the owners viewcontroller list  (i.e. `const selectedIndex = owner._ios.viewControllers.indexOfObject(viewController);` )